# Mostrar imagen en ventana modal con petición ajax

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

Tengo la siguiente ruta para mostrar una imagen protegiendo mi carpeta `storage` para usuarios que no están autenticados

```
Route::get('/storage/{archivo}', function ($archivo) { 
  if(!auth()->user()) 
  { 
    return abort(404);
  } 
  else
  {

    $path = URL::to('/storage'.'/'.$archivo);
    $path = storage_path('app/public') . '/' . $archivo;
    $file = \File::get($path);
    $type = \File::mimeType($path);

    return \Response::make($file,200)->header("Content-Type", $type);
  }
});
```

Cuando ingreso a la url `localhost/storage/imagen.jpg` la imagen se muestra a la perfección, no se como pueda insertar esa imagen en una venta modal de una vista `blade`

Este es mi código, el método se ejecuta con éxito, solo quiero insertar la imagen:

```
  $('#verDocumentoModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

    var imagen = $(e.relatedTarget).data('url_imagen');
    var idPartner = $(e.relatedTarget).data('idPartner');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'storage'+'/'+imagen,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (json) {
                $('#verDocumentoModal .modal-body #imagen_url').attr("src", json);
            }
    });

});
```

Que método `jquery` puedo usar para mostrar la imagen en el modal?

Comment: Porque hacer una peticion ajax?, no creo que sea necesario

Answer (score 1):

Por que no devuelves solo la ruta de la imagen, en vez de un json

```
Route::get('/storage/{archivo}', function ($archivo) { 
      if(!auth()->user()) 
      { 
        return abort(404);
      } 
      else
      {

        $path = URL::to('/storage'.'/'.$archivo);
        $path = storage_path('app/public') . '/' . $archivo;
        $file = \File::get($path);
        $type = \File::mimeType($path);

        return "storage/imagen.jpg";//aquí pones la ruta para devolverla como string
      }
    }); 

    $('#verDocumentoModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var imagen = $(e.relatedTarget).data('url_imagen');
        var idPartner = $(e.relatedTarget).data('idPartner');
        var modal = $(this)

        $.ajax({
            url: 'storage'+'/'+imagen,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (json) {
                    modal.find('#imagen_url').attr("src", json);
                }
        });

    });
```

De igual manera si es muy necesario devolver el *json*, tienes que poner en vez de el *json* completo, la ruta de la imagen que debe estar dentro dicho *json*

```
 modal.find('#imagen_url').attr("src", "ruta_de_la_imagen");
```

Ya que estas poniendo una imagen en el atributo src cuando en realidad solo debe tener la ruta de la imagen